# Ubuntu on an Asus EEE PC 4G (701)

Tags: asus, eeepc

I'm a new user to Ubuntu, but having installed it on my main laptop I found that I really like the UI and the usability.

I have an Asus eee PC 4G that's been sitting spare for a few years now and would love to be able to get Ubuntu installed on it but I'm unsure on what distro to pick for it as when I tried with the same version I put on my main laptop it came up with a CPU compatibility error.

So any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of other nostalgic owners of the (old but still cute) Eee PC.

After some fight, today (2018/12/8) I managed to install Lubuntu 12-04 on my Eee PC 4G, portuguese keyboard and all.

What I learned:

- The oficial repository seems to be broken but this mirror is up: https://phillw.net/isos/lubuntu/precise/
- The alternate installers of versions 16.04 and 12.04 won't install.
- The desktop versions of 14-04 and 16.04 won't work al all.
- The desktop installer of 12.04 works but when trying to install complains about the SDD being smaller than 4.4GB. The trick to overcome this was to plug in a pendrive with more than 4.4GB and then it installed by default on the internal SDD with 1GB still to spare.

Comment: An alternative is to create a **persistent live system** in the 4 GB SSD in your eeePC. The main image is compressed (from the iso file), and there will be more drive space available for extra program packages and your own data files (to be saved in the `casper-rw` file or partition). [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) creates persistent live drives with `casper-rw` *partitions* for 14.04 and newer versions. You can use **Unetbootin** to create a persistent live drive with a `casper-rw` *file* for Lubuntu 12.04 (I tested Unetbootin version 667 in Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS).

Comment: I have installed Xubuntu 14.04 LTS in a friend's eeePC 900. This is a full installation which works in that computer with a 9 GB SSD.

Answer (score 2):

So for whatever reason I found myself looking for a Linux distribution for the Asus Eee PC 4G (701) today, in 2019 :D

Right now I am running [BunsenLabs Linux](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/) Helium on it, from image `bl-Helium-4-i386.iso`. For installation troubleshooting, see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130998). This distro is based on Debian 9, so pretty close to a recent Ubuntu. It runs nicely, with most of the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keyboard shortcuts etc. working out of the box, and still is very compact (~120 MiB main memory usage after start). Also, since it's Debian based, the `.deb` packaging system and package names etc. are all the same as in Ubuntu, and you can even add packages from Ubuntu repositories.

**About the CPU incompatibility issue**

My first guess was that you might need a non-PAE kernel for this computer. PAE is "physical address extension", allowing a 32-bit processor to access main memory beyond 4 GiB. Normal Ubuntu / Lubuntu boot options in current releases fail to start the Linux kernel on non-PAE CPUs. The Eee PC 4G (701) uses a CPU "Intel Celeron M Processor ULV 353", which supports 32-bit Physical Address Extension (PAE), [according to the specs](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27157/intel-celeron-m-processor-ulv-353-512k-cache-900-mhz-400-mhz-fsb.html). So it turns out that it is **not** necessary to utilize a non-PAE distribution. I installed a regular (PAE based) kernel, and it runs just fine.

So I am not sure what causes the "CPU incompatibility" issue in your case. Side note: Though I did not need it for this model of computer, some CPUs falsely advertise that they don't support PAE when in fact they do. In these cases, you can force the execution of a PAE kernel with with kernel options `forcepae -- forcepae` ([detailed instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE)).

Comment: Can you write a blog post or something somewhere detailing how did you install BunsenLabs Linux on ASUS EEEPC 701 ? I found my computer on a drawer and it still holds 2:30 hours charge so I was curious if I could install some more recent Linux distro on it.

Comment: @eri0o Please see my other answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130998). It covers all the main problems I experienced during the installation. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is the architecture version you tried 64bit? For a EEE PC 701 4G, you need to install the 32bit version.

You don't say what version Ubuntu you tried. I have had 10.04 running for a few years now, and have previously booted 12.04 as a LiveUSB.

Answer (score 1):

For the EEE 701 I have tried a lot of different versions of Ubuntu. Now I am very content with the "Peppermint ICE" version.
The connections go very good and you still can add a lot of functional apps.

So try it! 
Let me now.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, that machine uses a Celeron M processor that does not support Physical Address Extensions (PAE), so the error you were likely getting was something like, "This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae."

You will need a 32 bit distribution that supports non-pae processors, which is getting harder to find.  [You might try reading this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE) for wisdom on getting Lubuntu or Xubuntu working on this machine.  However it did not run very well the last time I tried it. I ended up trying to use bodhi Linux, which i believe still has a non-pae supporting kernel available. I also gave puppy Linux a good run, but that one doesn't like to be installed, but rather run as a bootable live image.

If you are feeling particularly crafty, I've heard talked of folks getting arch Linux working on these. You will have to pull out your best Google foo for that one though.

Good luck!

Comment: In fact, the CPU of the Eee PC 4G (701) does support PAE. I am running a PAE kernel on it without issues ([details](https://askubuntu.com/a/1131000)).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following link http://www.eeebuntu.org/release/eeebuntu or as another option would be maybe a netbook remix version of ubuntu on one of the archive versions. I did this a while ago and used an image unpacked onto an SD card to perform the install, after some settings changes in the BIOS (had to flash new BIOS version) to change the boot order it was pretty simple.

Comment: I made a USB installer from the release on that site, but it still will not try to boot from the USB, it just boots to desktop and opens it in a file explorer.
I seem to have changed the boot order in the BIOS, but it still just loads the desktop... frustrating!

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Since it just have 512MB ram. I would advise against running the regular Ubuntu - Unity, Gnome or KDE version. It would be better to use lightweight version like Lubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu. Your eeePC has a 32 bit processor, so try installing 32-bit version of these distributions. The best choice would be **Lubuntu 14.04.4 LTS**. [Download Here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/)

Comment: Note that main memory on the Eee PC 4G (701) can be upgraded to 1×2 GiB ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asus_Eee_PC#Specifications)).